# ShouldBeEquivalentTo for objects with different types

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

In my test I have the result of type `HttpRequestMessage` and I need to assert that it's property `Content` is set to correct object.

The problem is that `HttpRequestMessage.Content` has a different (base) type than the object I want to compare with and I can't use ShouldBeEquivalentTo and Including like this:

```
HttpRequestMessage result = ...

result.Content.ShouldBeEquivalentTo (new ObjectContent (obj.GetType (), obj, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter ()),
                                     options => options.Including (x => x.Value));
```

This does not compile because options working with Content property type (which is `HttpContent`) and not with `ObjectContent`.

The only way I found is to have two assertions like this:

```
result.Should ().BeOfType<ObjectContent> ();

((ObjectContent) result.Content).ShouldBeEquivalentTo (new ObjectContent (obj.GetType (), obj, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter ()),
                                                        options => options.Including (x => x.Value));
```

Is there a better way to do it? Maybe some kind of `BeOfType` which returns casted object fluent assertion instead of the base one?

Comment: Can't use the overload that provides you with an `ISubjectInfo` object? Then you can use a text-based matched on the property path.

Comment: Dennis, if you mean reflection, then I think it would be even more uglier.

Comment: No no, there's an overload that provides you with a Func<> to an ISubjectInfo. And that object provides access to the full property path that you might be able to get the same effect. Look at the example in https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/blob/master/FluentAssertions.Specs/EquivalencySpecs.cs at line 533.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. But it's magic strings which are subject to break on refactoring :(

Comment: I agree. But that's why have unit tests in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of a simpler way, but if you are trying to avoid the ugly code in multiple places, an extension method might work well:

Something like (I'm not sure if this will compile as is):

```
public static class ShouldBeHelper
{
    public static void ShouldBeSameContent(this HttpRequestMessage result, object expected)
    {
        result.Should().BeOfType<ObjectContent>();

        ((ObjectContent)result.Content).ShouldBeEquivalentTo(new ObjectContent(expected.GetType(), expected, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(),
            options => options.Including(x => x.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, we can use extensions but I was thinking that it should be possible with the library itself instead of writing extensions all the time.